# How to get the directory of an .exe without arguments VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file

I have a one route:

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Download Manager\IDMan.exe /onboot
```

and I want to get this route like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Download Manager\IDMan.exe
```

Without the argument, how could I do this in VB.NET?

Comment: What have you tried to do and what is not working?

Comment: I tried to separate the path and the executable and then join them, but the GetFileName, I get: IDMan.exe / onboot and I need is just the IDMan.exe.
`dim str1 as string = "C:\Program Files\Internet Download Manager\IDMan.exe /onboot"
Dim Ruta as string = GetPath(str1) & GetFileName(str1)`

Comment: This is much harder to do correctly than might it might seem.  Windows has to solve it and that sometimes goes wrong, many users have been flummoxed by "C:\Program is not recognized.." .  The proper way to address the problem is by not having to solve it.  Surely you are doing this to use the Process class.  Note that the ProcessStartInfo class uses separate fields for these two data items, FileName and Arguments.  So a logical way to get ahead is to use ProcessStartInfo instead of String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the assumption that all your parameters are separated from the file name by a space and a a forward slash, this should work. The long winded way is below and a condensed version is below that.

```
Dim s As String = "C:\Program Files\Internet Download Manager\IDMan.exe /onboot"
Dim intermediatesplits As String() = s.Split(New String() {" /"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim result As String = intermediatesplits(0)
```

The important function is `.Split` which is most often used with one character as the parameter, however you can use two characters like above.

and the condensed version

```
Dim s As String = "C:\Program Files\Internet Download Manager\IDMan.exe /onboot"
Dim result As String = s.Split(New String() {" /"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(0)
```